# Angular2 Component @Input two way binding

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, components, decorator

I have a data driven Angular application.  I have a toggle component which I pass in a toggled state.  My issue is that the two way data binding does not seem to work unless i pass in the toggle boolean as an object.  Is there a way to get this to work **without using an EventEmitter or passing the variable in as an object**.  This is to be a reusable component and the application is heavily data driven so passing the value in as an object in not an option.  My code is....

toggle.html

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="toggled" [id]="toggleId" name="check"/>
```

toggle.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'toggle-switch',
  templateUrl: 'toggle-switch.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['toggle-switch.component.css']
})

export class ToggleSwitchComponent {

  @Input() toggleId: string;
  @Input() toggled: boolean;

}
```

parent.component.html

```
<toggle-switch toggleId="toggle-1" [(toggled)]="nongenericObject.toggled"></toggle-switch>
```

Comment: I'd like to stress the importance of mitch's comment on this. To make two-way-binding with a parent component's var work, the `@Output` decorated EventEmitter has to be named as the corresponding `@Input` with a **Change** suffix at the end as in: @Input() toggled: boolean; @Output() toggledChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

Answer (score 165, accepted):

For `[(toggled)]="..."` to work you need

```
  @Input() toggled: boolean;
  @Output() toggledChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  changeValue() {
    this.toggled = !(this.toggled); 
    this.toggledChange.emit(this.toggled);
  }
```

See also [Two-way binding](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding)

[UPDATE] - 25 June 2019
From @Mitch's comment below:
It's worth noting that the `@Output` name must be the same as the `@Input` name, but with `Change` on the end. You can't call it `onToggle` or something. It's a syntax convention.

Comment: He even imported `EventEmitter`. It might not as bad as you expect ;-)

Comment: This actually worked for me.  I had originally had it set up to use the event emitter which was linked to a function in the parent component. That wasnt very reusable hence why i asked the question to see if there was a way to do this.  This answer for some reason changes the parent toggled variable

Comment: Isn't that the intention? I assume `nongenericObject.toggled` is "the parent toggled variable"?

Comment: Yes it is the parent value.  Thankyou it worked.  I've spent half a day trying to get this to work and you've sorted it in seconds.

Comment: @silentsod It's nonetheless rather annoying that Angular doesn't have a built-in way to handle 2-way binding on one attribute. Seems like a super basic feature; yet, it's simply not supported. Also, the Angular docs are incredibly convoluted and difficult to comprehend, so I wouldn't be surprised if OP didn't understand how to do this even after reading them.

Comment: It's worth noting that the `@Output` name must be the same as the `@Input` name, but with `Change` on the end.  You can't call it `onToggle` or something.  It's a syntax convention.

Comment: @Mitch: Wow! This has frustrated me for weeks! Is there anywhere in the documentation that describes this convention? There surely must be... I just must have missed it.

Comment: @ProxyTech it is documented here: https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding: `The [()] syntax is easy to demonstrate when the element has a settable property called x and a corresponding event named xChange`. However I agree that this should be emphasized.

Comment: The docs have improved a LOT since back then in the good old times :D

Comment: @Mitch Wow! Had no idea about this "convention". Thank you. Absolutely bizarre that a modern web framework (in 2024) is relying on obscure hard-coded naming conventions (of symbols!!! not even string constants but symbols) for what is seemingly very rudimentary functionality. Insanity.

Answer (score 13):

Although the question has more than 2 years old I want to contribute my 5 cents...

It isn't a problem about Angular, its about how Javascript works... Simple variables (number, string, boolean, etc)  are passed by value whereas complex ones (objects, arrays) are passed by reference:

You can read more about this in Kyle Simpson´s series You dont know js:

https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch2.md#value-vs-reference

So, you can use an @Input() object variable to share scope between components without need to use emitters, observers and whatever similar.

```
// In toggle component you define your Input as an config object
@Input() vm: Object = {};

// In the Component that uses toggle componet you pass an object where you define all needed needed variables as properties from that object:
config: Object = {
    model: 'whateverValue',
    id: 'whateverId'
};

<input type="checkbox" [vm]="config" name="check"/>
```

This way you can modify all object properties and you get same value in both components because they share same reference.

Comment: This can both be a blessing and a nightmare. I've had a real bad time once because the reference was being passed and I didn't know and a bug ticket was created. I couldn't understand why it was happening, even creating new objects and so on. But now, I just needed a simple two way binding and it works perfectly

Comment: Link is broken - looks like they're partway through a new edition but the original is still there:  https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/types%20%26%20grammar/ch2.md#value-vs-reference