# Angular: 2 way data binding for a custom input in a child component

Tags: angular, 2-way-object-databinding

How to make 2-way data binding for a custom input in child component in Angular 8?

I used banana-in-a-box `[(...)]` syntax but it doesn't make changes in child component visible in the parent component.

In the result, it should work with the banana-in-a-box syntax.

**parent.component.ts**

```
...
public childVisibility: boolean = true;
...
```

**parent.component.html**

```html
childVisibility : {{childVisibility}}

<app-child-component [(visible)]="childVisibility">
</app-child-component>
```

**child.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-component',
  templateUrl: './app-child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./global-search-results.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() visible: boolean;

  constructor() {}

  public changeVisible() { 
    this.visible = false;
  }
}
```

**child.component.html**

```html
<button (click)="changeVisible()">
  Change Visible
</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006770/angular2-component-input-two-way-binding

Comment: can please what you trying to do here >> trying to accept as input or emit as output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Component @Input two way binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006770/angular2-component-input-two-way-binding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**child.component.ts**

```
@Input()  visible: boolean;
@Output() visibleChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

public changeVisible() { 
   this.visible = false;
   this.visibleChange.emit(this.visible);
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<app-child-component [(visible)]="childVisibility">
</app-child-component>
```

The cause here is the suffix 'Change' in the event's name `visibleChange`. If the property binding name is 'x', the event binding name should be exactly 'xChange'. Only then angular recognizes banana-in-a-box [()] syntax.

Detailed example: http://embed.plnkr.co/Jcu0iNkaUeRF7KEF7wA4/

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

**child.component.ts:**

```
@Output() visibleChange = new EventEmitter();

public makeVisible() { 
   this.visible = false;
   this.visibleChange.emit(this.visible)
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<app-child-component [(visible)]="childVisibility" >
</app-child-component>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-foftcq?embed=1&file=src/app/child/child.component.ts)**

Comment: Not bad custom example but you forgot about the dependency in the naming between `visible` and `visibleChange`. I mean the next: `@Input()  visible: boolean; @Output() visibleChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();`

Comment: Which dependency?

Comment: The cause is the suffix 'Change' in the event's name visibleChange. I mean this.